# (mobile) How to keep the nav bar hidden during scrolling

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, scroll, navbar

I'm working on this: [mobiledoor](http://www.reveriesrefined.com/myftp/mobiledoor)
for Mobile, and I want to hide the nav bar and keep it hidden.
I'm already using:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}, 500);
```

To hide the nav bar initially and on orientation changes, however, I want the nav bar to stay hidden during scrolling. I'd like it to work where the only way for them to see the nav bar is, on iphone anyway, where they touch the top of the screen. Obviously, it's already hidden just fine while scrolling down the page, but when you scroll back to the top it will display the nav bar and I'd really like to keep it hidden.

I was thinking something along the lines of triggering this on touch end

```
if (window.scrollY < 2) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }, 0);
    }
```

but the problem is that when you scroll to the top, it shows the nav bar temporarily then goes to (0,1). I want it to not show the nav bar at all.

although I can't seem to get it to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Considering just moving the whole site down by a few hundred pixels and setting it so that if scrollY < 300 it will scroll to 300. That way there would be plenty of space between the nav bar and the viewable site... although I'm hoping that someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that comes to mind is putting an event listener on scroll, eg.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollTop < 44) {
    window.scrollTop = 44;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately putting listeners onScroll is highly unperformant, and generally frowned upon. If you absolutely 100% need the functionality, use a throttled listener so that your function doesn't fire more often than, say, every 10ms.

Comment: I don't think I could afford to have it any slower, there's already a lot of images and a lot of code involved, I think I may just have to deal with it.

I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have 15 reputation points...

Comment: No problem, glad to help! (Sort of..)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, I think I will just move the whole site down on the y axis by 2000px and then find an image of that background grey scratchy pattern that the iphone has when you've scrolled too far, and put it above on the y axis so that it looks like if you scroll up, it's too far.

Answer (score -1):

You should have to implement scrollview delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is or what it does, could you explain a little bit?

Comment: He is talking about something totally different. Objective-C programming, with iOS Devices.